# wp_Qwery works to slow

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb, select

I have 266 806 rows in `wp_posts`, and when I'm trying to get post this help of `WP_Query` or DB `SELECT` which sort parameters it's gets results more when 0.3ms

Exemple of `SELECT`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1482,2734) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 5  
(WP_Query->get_posts,   0,4108ms)
```

(I'm using cache only for non login users)

How can I optimize `SELECT` to make request time shorter?